# The system is running in low -graphics mode

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, kali-linux-tools

I got this message that the system is running in low graphics mode.
So I did the necessary to try and install the NVidia drivers.
I tried booting in *recovery mode* and use failsafe x.
Then I run:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

This seemed to download the necessary drivers.
I should mention that I installed `katoolin`, which allowed me to install some of *Kali linux* tools and I installed some, such as `wireshark`, `nmap` etc.
Now, when I update the system, it takes its update from Ubuntu and Kali.

But the weird thing is:
After I installed the NVidia drivers, I noticed it was getting its update from both Kali and Ubuntu. So it overwrote my installation of Ubuntu and replaced it with Kali. But I am still getting the message

> the system is running in low graphics mode

However, I can open a terminal via <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>. I can see my files with `ls`, but the system is not loading up so i can login from the login screen.
Any suggestions or guidance on what can be done?
I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Katoolin from crashing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895546/how-to-stop-katoolin-from-crashing-ubuntu)