# What is "failed to create symbolic link" error?

Tags: permissions, xubuntu, firefox, directory

I am trying to create symbolic link for Firefox using this command:

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/firefox/firefox': No such file or directory
```

I have tried doing it with `-sv` but same result

Comment: Does directory `/usr/lib/firefox/` exist?

Answer (score 0):

The `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox` file only exists if the default Firefox from the Ubuntu repositories is installed. Reinstalling it with `sudo apt install firefox` would remove this error message. It would also be appropriate to [check](https://askubuntu.com/q/895546/) if installing packages with Kali Linux tools uninstalled any other applications which are installed by default in Xubuntu.