# Ubuntu MATE on RPi doesn't connect to Ethernet after installing Katoolin (unsure if it's related)

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet, dhcp, raspberrypi

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and I'm running Ubuntu Mate 18.04.2 on my Raspberry Pi 3 B

The Ethernet just doesn't work and so does the Wi-Fi connection. In the  Network Connections panel, the last used column says that the nor the Ethernet or the Wi-Fi connection hasn't been used, so I don't know how I can make it to use the Ethernet / Wi-Fi. I don't know why or how this happened and I've tried reconfiguring the network settings many times. DHCP is enabled in my router. I've also edited `/etc/network/interface` but that didn't work.

I've recently installed Katoolin and some categories from it. I don't know if that had an influence on my internet connection. That was yesterday and yesterday I did have Ethernet connection.

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try Reinstalling Ubuntu, format the /boot and bootloader partition, back up files in 1 or 2 partitions and do a reinstall. That should do you no harm except for the updates you'll lose. Ask me to elaborate if you're interested in reinstalling

Comment: Don't edit `/etc/network/interfaces` unless you want to configure network manually. It disables Network Manager.

Comment: Do you think a factory reset would also work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Katoolin from crashing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895546/how-to-stop-katoolin-from-crashing-ubuntu)