# Katoolin post-installation size on Ubuntu

Tags: katoolin

I'm running Ubuntu Mate 18 on Windows 7 dual boot and I specified just a small space for it Ubuntu (45 GB). I need to know the Katoolin size after installing all Kali tools, and if i can install it on `/home`, and if it is compatible with my Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Katoolin from crashing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895546/how-to-stop-katoolin-from-crashing-ubuntu) Many of the tools in katoolin are also provided by the default Ubuntu repositories and are not installed in `/home` by `sudo apt install`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so Katolin takes that much size . The total size of Katoolin3 directory is 17mb. I've only installed 3 tools if you want to install all the Kali Linux tools it would definitely take a much larger size but if you want to download specific tools you can download it in 45Gb easily