# error in installing wine with unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, upgrade, wine, dependencies

I am trying to install WINE on Ubuntu
and when I run `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: mutter (< 3.31.4) but 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

before installing but it does not work

The output of `sudo apt update`

```
$ sudo apt update 
Hit:1 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:5 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease
Hit:6 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Hit:8 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Hit:7 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease                         
Hit:9 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                             
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1328 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (non-free/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (non-free/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list:1
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1254316/edit) to show the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: Are you using Kali or Ubuntu? If you are using Ubuntu, you shouldn't be having Kali's repositories configured in the first place. Were these repositories added by Katoolin? If you try to upgrade those 1328 packages, you'll end up with a broken system. Consider removing them before taking any further action.

Comment: yeah i have Kali's repositories i will remove them then try

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times) Also see [How to stop Katoolin from crashing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895546)