# Cannot execute Katoolin/Cannot get +x permission

Tags: permissions, chmod, katoolin

I have done all the steps required to run Katoolin, but I still get the message:  sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/katoolin: No such file or directory

Now I am able to do the chmod +x command w/o the system returning an error.  However, when I go into /usr/bin and search for katoolin I find it, a 51.3kb file.  Here's the issue under permissions it lists root(owner no read no write, group none), but I cannot click the drop down boxes, executable box is greyed out?  Security context is unknown.

The chmod command is successful in terminal, but no change takes place when I view properties?  I am at a complete loss. How can I get it to execute?

Comment: For the katoolin file in /usr/bin these are the current permissions with ls -l katoolin:  root@Cyberdyne101:/usr/bin# ls -l katoolin
---x--xrwx 1 root root 51305 Nov 16 18:57 katoolin

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/829672/692175

Comment: If `/usr/bin/katoolin` is a *script*, then it will need to be *readable* as well as executable

Comment: Well I'm still getting the same error, and I now have read and write.  root@Cyberdyne101:/usr/bin# ls -l katoolin
-rwxr-xrwx 1 root root 51305 Nov 16 20:00 katoolin
root@Cyberdyne101:/usr/bin# sudo katoolin
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/katoolin: No such file or directory      I would also like to add I find it strange that is lists execute as a permission with ls -l, but when I right-click the file and go to Properties/Permissions all drop down boxes are greyed and executable box is greyed and no execute is listed under Owner or Group?